# Kernel of a Nilpotent Mapping Restricted to a Generalised Eigenspce

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator with eigenvalue $\lambda$, with matrix representation $A$.
Is it true that the nilpotent mapping $N = (T-\lambda Id)|_{K_\lambda}$ satisfies
$$Nullity(N) = Nullity(A-\lambda I)$$
and $$Nullity(N^2) = Nullity((A-\lambda I)^2)$$

and so forth?

(Do note that $K_\lambda$ is the generalised eigenspace of $\lambda$).

Comment: The answer is no: $\ker N$ is a subspace of $V$, but $\ker(A - \lambda I)$ is a subspace of $\Bbb C^n$

Comment: I have altered the notation of my question, so as to evade this problem.

Comment: The answer to your new question is yes. To show this, it suffices to note that $\ker(A - \lambda I) \subset K_{\lambda}$, which is simply to say that the genralized eigenspace necessarily contains the eigenspace.